# Jsp:Include Throwing Nonspecific Error

Tags: jsp, jspinclude, sling, aem

I am trying to pass a Boolean variable to an include page, but the error I'm receiving is not helpful. I'm also very new to JSP so I'm adapting to reading Java-based error logs.

```
<%
boolean publications = false;
%>

<jsp:include page="scopusfeed.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="publications" value="<%= publications %>" />
</jsp:include>
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
    Error Message:

    org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: 
    Processing Info:

    Page    =   /content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco   
    Resource Path   =   /content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco/jcr:content/facultymember 
    Cell    =   facultymember   
    Cell Search Path    =   facultymemberpage|popuppage|standardpage|page/facultymember|parbase 
    Component Path  =   /apps/tju/components/content/faculty/facultymember  
    Sling Request Progress:

          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) COMMENT timer_end format is {,} 
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco.html/publications
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco.html/publications resolves to Resource=JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco', selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='/publications'
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco)}
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(JcrNodeResource, type=cq:Page, superType=null, path=/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco)} Using servlet /libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/content/tju/population_health/faculty/abatemarco.html/publications handled by Servlet=/libs/foundation/components/primary/cq/Page/Page.jsp
          0 (2012-02-01 12:33:03) LOG Applying Requestfilters
.......... more of the same
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the included jsp **scopusfeed.jsp** separately with the parameter.

There is no issue with your code. I believe there is some error in the included jsp itself. call **scopusfeed.jsp?publications=false** and then have a look at the errors.

That could clarify the actual error.

Comment: As it turns out, so far, Adobe CQ5 doesn't get along well with the <jsp:include> tag.  So this post cannot be answered at this time.  Thanks, though.